# prisma client not see schema in globally installed node_modules

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, prisma

I currently develop a nodejs cli with prisma and planning to ship sqlite3 db with @prisma/client.

npm creates symnlink between bin file and the package downloaded under the folder node_modules. When I run globally installed package from any location, @prisma/client complained about mongo url (sqlite db source is in schema.) which means not see my schema under the node_modules.

Any idea of how to ship prisma client with node cli program?

Here is my schema

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:database.db"
}

...
...
```

here is the bin location of my package `/opt/homebrew/bin/my-package`

here is where package is loaded with its schema and its node_modules `/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/my-package`

Here is the error message provided by prisma/client

```
  error: Error validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the protocol `mongo`.
  -->  schema.prisma:11
   |
10 |   provider = "mongodb"
11 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
```